# Three-level or four-level meta-analysis?

Tags: multilevel-analysis, meta-analysis

Sometimes, in a meta-analysis, it happens that studies include more than one independent sample and multiple component outcomes are reported for each sample. Which model would be more reasonable to use, three-level or four-level meta-analysis?

I have read the two nice papers “[Three-level meta-analysis of dependent effect sizes](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/23055166/)” and “[Meta-analysis of multiple outcomes: a multilevel approach](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/25361866/)” by Prof. Wim Van den Noortgate, et al. In three-level meta-analysis, for dependences like multiple outcomes from the same study (i.e., correlated effects), the dependence was modelled as hierarchical effects, that is, the three-level model for correlated effects was: level 1-sample, level 2-outcome, level 3-study, whereas for hierarchical effects, level 1-sample, level 2-sub-study, level 3-study.

My question is: if the two types of dependence occur in the same meta-analysis, would it be considered reasonable to conduct a four-level meta-analysis, i.e., level 1–sample, level 2–outcome, level 3–sub-study, and level 4–study? Or conduct a three-level meta-analysis, i.e., level 1–sample, level 2–outcome/sub-study, and level 3–study? Would there be a general requirement for the number of units in each level? If using three-level model, it seems difficult to interpret the variance estimate on level 2.

Comment: The four level model seems to fit your data structure best.

Comment: @mdewey thank you!